# "Newest questions" button missing when returning from meta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta

When coming back to the main page from Meta, the usual questions show up, put the "newest" filter is missing. It re-appears if I click at the "questions" tab again. Is this a bug?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a bug and it's not missing, it only displays under the [*Questions* section](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions), never on the [*Main* page](https://space.stackexchange.com/). These are two different layouts and you likely navigated from *Questions* section to our *[Meta](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com)*, then returned back to the *Main* site using the top bar link. Top bar menu does not remember which layout you had last selected on either *Main* or *Meta* site (tho there was a discussion somewhere if such should persist with cookies, I guess it was only implemented for display options in individual sections themselves, such as page size and active display tab).